Как в BeautifulSoup получить текст страницы в <body> с пробелами между текстом в разных тегах
Цель: получить текст из HTML при помощи BeautifulSoup.
Текст берется из любых текстовых тегов, за исключением тегов  a .
Не нашел как можно добавить пробел если текст берется из рядом стоящих тегов. Иначе текст сливается между собой.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<html>
<body>
  <div>
         <p>Hello</p><p>World <a href='/'>Ancor World</a></p>
         <p>Cat And</p><p>Dog</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
text_a = ' '.join([tag.getText() for tag in a_tags])

body = soup.find('body')
for a in body.find_all('a'):
    a.replace_with(' ')
body_text = body.getText()
print(text_a)
print(body_text)

Вывод кода:
Текст ссылок:
Ancor World - ок.
Остальной текст в body: HelloWorld   Cat AndDog
Не ок, текст сливается, нужно: Hello World   Cat And Dog
Работающее решение
Использовать body_text = body.get_text(separator=' ')
вместо body_text = body.getText()

.get_text(separator=' ') https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140143/how-to-add-space-around-removed-tags-in-beautifulsoup

print(*body.strings) или print(*body.stripped_strings)

Ну так вам нужно разделить пробелами теги p, а не теги a. Попробуйте например заменить код:
body_text = body.getText()

На код:
body_text = ' '.join(tag.getText() for tag in body.find_all('p'))

Вывод:
Ancor World
Hello World   Cat And Dog


Возможны варианты, где текст будет форматирован другими тегами. И конечный текст может быть в div, span и пр.
Вариант с
body_text = ' '.join(tag.getText() for tag in body.find_all('p'))
На данном примере подходит.
Но если взять более общий, то часть текста не войдет.
Вариант использования без указания тега p
body_text = ' '.join(tag.getText() for tag in body.find_all()
Приводит к задвоению текста в данном случае:
HelloWorld   Cat AndDog  Hello World   Cat And Dog

Сработало использование  body_text =  body.get_text(separator=' ')
